# Pass a foreach loop of forms to Twig

Tags: forms, foreach, twig, symfony5

I am creating an edit page where there will be as many forms as there will be results from my query. So after my query, I created a foreach loop to pass each "result" to a form and then I pass it all to my Twig.

```
$repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Classement::class);
    
    $q = $repo->createQueryBuilder('c');
    $q->select('c', 'h')
      ->join('c.clubHistos', 'h')
      ->where('c.country = '.$country)
      ->where('c.season = '.$season);
    $result = $q->getQuery()->getResult();


    foreach ($result as $table) {
        $table  = $table;
        
        $form = $this->createForm(ClassementType::class, $table);
    }
    
    return $this->render('back/editDivisionTables.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'table' => $table
    ));
```

The problem is that I am only getting the last form when I should be having all of them. I did a dump($form) in my loop and everything seemed okay. So the problem is either in my return statement or in my Twig.

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
        <div class="season-table-info">
            <div class="country">
                {{ form_row(form.country) }}
            </div>
            <div class="division">
                {{ form_row(form.division) }}
            </div>
            {{ form_row(form.season) }}
        </div>

        <table id="dynamic-club-table">
            <thead></thead>

            <tbody id="dynamic-club-table-body" data-row-prototype="{{ formMacro.form(form.clubHistos.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
                {% for clubHistos in form.clubHistos %}
                    {{ formMacro.form(clubHistos) }}
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125602/symfony-2-multiple-forms-generated-list-of-objects/30128615#30128615) but it didn't do the trick.

Comment: This line `$form = $this->createForm(ClassementType::class, $table);` overwrites `$form` with a new form for every `$table`. Meaning, you actually only have one form. The question is, do you want one form with repeating elements, or repeating forms (including separate submit buttons and the like)?

Comment: I want repeating forms (so one form for each `$table`).

Comment: Then you'd need to create a list of forms, probably something like `$forms[] = ...`. In turn, you would need multiple `->createView(), ->handleRequest(...)` calls. And ultimately in your view, you'd need to iterate over `forms` to render each individual form.

Comment: Also, because this is always the same form, I think you'll need [named forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#changing-the-form-name) to distinguish between them *on submit*.

Comment: I did `$forms[$table->getId()] = $this->createForm(ClassementType::class, $table)->createView();` and now I have all my forms. But when I proceed to the handling of the form (`handleRequest()`, `isSubmitted()`, `isValid()`) I get an error saying these methods are undefined.